# unresolved external symbol "private: static float ObjectInfo::Rotation

Tags: c++, class, static-members, unresolved-external

```
    #include <iostream>

class ObjectInfo{
private:
    static float Rotation;
public:
    //sets object rotation value
    void SetR(float a){ static float Rotation = a; }
    //print roation value (I think this is where the problem is located)
    void PrintR(){ std::cout << Rotation;}
};

int main()
{
    ObjectInfo Wall;
    //set float var
    float Rotation;
    //Get user set rotation
    std::cin >> Rotation;
    //set wall rotation
    Wall.SetR(Rotation);
    //print wall rotation value
    Wall.PrintR();
    std::cin >> Rotation;
}
```

Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static float ObjectInfo::Rotation" (?Rotation@ObjectInfo@@0MA)

Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

> This is a protype i made and i have no clue how to resolve the error.
>
> Does anynyone know what could cause this error?
>
> I get the same error if i try returning the value and then couting that value.
>
> Does anyone know an alteriate solution to retreaving the value from the class?

Comment: This answer in particular: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574407/1413395

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allocate storage for your static member, need

```
float ObjectInfo::Rotation;
```

outside your class definition.

Comment: Thanks allot that wasn't the most obvious thing in c++ to figure out. Thanks for your help.